# why does the gpio pin in raspberry pi get set to 1 when a set the pin mode as input?

Tags: raspberry-pi

why does the gpio pin in raspberry pi get set to 1 when the pin is set in input mode and vice-versa?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaKxu.png)

for example, in the attached screenshot the GPIO.0 is set in input mode and its Voltage level is 1.